# JQuery Mobile & passing variables in links via the querystring - but the querystring doesn't refresh

Tags: jquery-mobile, query-string

I am doing a PhoneGap app with JQuery Mobile and I have two pages, one that has a dynamic list of pages and one that has a form to either edit or create a page. These are in a single html file.

Tapping on a list item passes ?action=edit and tapping the "Add" button I have, passes ?action=add querystrings.

[Here is a jsfiddle to visualize the pages](http://jsfiddle.net/ee32T/)

NOTE: The example doesn't act quite the same as the live code.

I am running my app on an Android phone and if I do these actions, the correct querysting is observed in the alert box: -

1. Click the add button on list page
2. Click back on the form page
3. Click the an edit list item link on list page

However, if I do it the other why around (click edit first, then the add button) clicking the add button never shows the add querystring in the alert box
(the jsfiddle example always locks the first clicked link's querystring, which is even worse than the live code!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is that you're using a multiple template to do this.  If you were using this as separate pages, this would work as normal. As a multiple app, the best way to handle this would be to make a link trigger the setting of some global variable that keeps track of the current state of the app.

Make the edit links like this

```
 <a href="javascript:editPage(15)">Page 15</a>
```

Then make the script something like this:

```
var editingId = 0

function editPage(id){
    editingId = id;
    $.mobile.changePage("#editingPage");
});

$("div#editingPage").live("pageshow", function(){
    loadDataForPage(editingId);
});
```